Point with polygon join returning a polyline
I'm new to spatial coding and I am trying to do a spatial join between a shapefile that has point information and a shapefile that has polygon information. The output should be a shapefile with the points in the polygon.
geofile = "stratmap24-landparcels_48201_lp/shp/stratmap24-landparcels_48201_harris_202407.shp"
polygons_gdf = gpd.read_file(geofile)

# contains polygon and multipolygon so converting everything to multipolygon
polygons_gdf['geometry'] = polygons_gdf['geometry'].apply(
    lambda geom: MultiPolygon([geom]) if geom.geom_type == 'Polygon' else geom
)

# Load the points from the shapefile
data = gpd.read_file("nsi_data/main_harris_data.shp")

# Create Point geometries from x and y columns
points_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data['x'], data['y']),
    crs=polygons_gdf.crs  # Ensure the CRS matches
)


point_gdf = points_gdf[:100]
points_within_polygons = gpd.sjoin( polygons_gdf,point_gdf, predicate='contains')
output_file = 'output_points_with_polygons.shp'
points_within_polygons.to_file(output_file)

Instead of returning a shapefile with polygons and points I'm getting polylines. Can anyone share their insight?
Note: there can be multiple points in a single polygon

Yes, this is the output - {'Polygon', 'MultiPolygon'}

I can't reproduce. I get Polygon output as expected, not PolyLine. What do you mean "with polygons and points"? You can't have more than one geometry type in a shapefile.

I want the points to appear along with the polygons. This polygon dataset is land parcels and the points are the individual buildings. I want the final shape file to have the parcel polygons with building points visible in them

That is not possible, you can only have one geometry type in a shapefile.

Yes, I used geopackages instead!
